# R mutate & replace string with empty pattern or empty string

Tags: r, str-replace, stringr, dplyr

I am trying to remove some pattern (`to_remove`) from another string column (`entry`) inside `mutate()`.

The problem is both my string and pattern columns contain some empty strings. So using some vectorized functions such as `stringr::str_remove()` would result some warnings and slow the process down by a lot.

I notice that without the empty strings & patterns (i.e. you replace them with some values) it would only take less than 1 sec to complete about 1e5 rows of records. However, with the warnings it would take over 10 secs.

I am wondering if there is any way I can use `stringr::str_remove()` inside `mutate()` but skipping those empty rows so that I can still have the speed benefit from vectorization.

Note that I can also use `dplyr::rowwise()` + `gsub()` but `rowwise()` slows things down a lot as well:(

Example code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)

set.seed(123)

temp <- data.frame(
  entry = c('A12','JW13','C','')
  ,to_remove = c('A','W','','D')
) %>%
  sample_n(1e5,replace = T)

temp <- temp %>%
  mutate(
    removed = str_remove(entry,to_remove)
  )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing the blank values with `NA` :

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

temp %>%
  mutate(to_remove = na_if(to_remove, ''),
         removed = str_remove(entry,to_remove))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
temp %>% 
   mutate(removed = str_remove(entry, replace(to_remove, to_remove == "", NA)))
```